# Creating json in java getting only first value not getting as desired format

Tags: java, json

I want to create a json array which looks like follows:

`[{"label":"Organisation 1","ID":2},{"label":"Organisation 2","ID":1},....]`

I did as follows :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                        while (rstcust.next()) {
                            obj.put("label", rstcust.getString(3));
                            obj.put("ID", rstcust.getInt(1));
                        }
                             out.print(obj);
```

I am getting only first value as output I am not getting like the fomat above:

I am getting the following output
`{"label":"Organisation 1","ID":2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating a `JSONObject` but what you need is a `JSONArray`

Create a `JSONArray` Object and then add individual JSONObjects into it.The code will be something like this.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
         while (rstcust.next()) {
              JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
              obj.put("label", rstcust.getString(3));
              obj.put("ID", rstcust.getInt(1));
              arr.put(obj);
              }
out.print(arr);
```

The JavaDocs for JSONArray can be found [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html).

In java 6 org.json.JSONArray contains the put method and in java 7 javax.json contains the add method.

Comment: Getting error `forstduser.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
                                                                  arr.put(obj);
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   method put(JSONObject)
  location: variable arr of type JSONArray`

Comment: @Santhucool: which library you are using for creating JSON Array?

Comment: in  java 7 javax.json contains the add method. try replacing `arr.put(obj)` with `arr.add(obj)`